# How to add an animation in progress bar UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, uibezierpath

I want to add an animation in my progress bar which is UIView based.
Here is my code.

```
@IBDesignable class PlainHorizontalProgressBar: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var color: UIColor = .green {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    var progress: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }
    
    private let progressLayer = CALayer()
    private let backgroundMask = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupLayers()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupLayers()
    }
    
    private func setupLayers() {
        layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        backgroundColor = .grey
        backgroundColor?.setFill()
        
        UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: rect.height * 0.25).fill()
        
        backgroundMask.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: rect.height * 0.25).cgPath
        layer.mask = backgroundMask
    
        let progressRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: rect.width * progress, height: rect.height))
    
        progressLayer.frame = progressRect
        layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
        progressLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    }

}
```

The scenario here is, I have ViewController A and ViewController B, This progress bar I have on ViewController B, I am assigning a value from ViewController A to ViewController B (example: myView.progress = 0.5 ) now when i am coming to ViewController B my progress bar is already filled half but what I want is, when I will come to ViewController B this should animate and filled front of me when I land on viewController B.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that your `draw` implementation is wrong. Or, to put it better, your `draw` implementation should not exist at all. The only thing that should happen in `draw` is drawing.

If you're going to add sublayers, you need a specific method that is called just once that adds the sublayers.

If you're going to change the frame of one of those sublayers, you need another specific method that changes the frame of the (already existing) sublayer. As soon as you separate that, it will be a lot more obvious how to animate the change in frame. In fact, because this is a layer, the animation will happen automatically.

[image]

```
class PlainHorizontalProgressBar: UIView {
    
    var color: UIColor = .green {
        didSet { update() }
    }

    var progress: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet { update() }
    }
    
    private let progressLayer = CALayer()
    private let backgroundMask = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupLayers()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupLayers()
    }
    
    private func setupLayers() {
        layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        backgroundMask.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: self.bounds.size.height * 0.25).cgPath
        layer.mask = backgroundMask
        update()
    }
    
    func update() {
        let progressRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: self.bounds.size.width * progress, height: self.bounds.size.height))
        progressLayer.frame = progressRect
        progressLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    }

}
```

The part about being allowed to set `progress` values between 1 and 100 is a matter of elementary arithmetic and is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: The issue still exist for me, let me explain my scenario, I have ViewController A and ViewController B, This progress bar I have on ViewController B, I am assigning a value from ViewController A to ViewController B (example: `myView.progress = 0.5` ) now when i am coming to ViewController B my progress is already filled half but what I want is, when I will come to ViewController B this should animate front of me and filled half, and that is not happening here.

Comment: I wrote you some working code that demonstrates how the progress can be animated. That’s all I’m interested in doing. It’s not my concern to satisfy other specifications revealed later. It’s easy to solve all of that based on my explanation.